# SSH with command Bat file

Tags: ssh, authentication, command, putty

I have created myself a bat file to log into putty but my question is how would I go about adding a command to the bat file so something like this I have already:

```
start [C:\Users\Public\Downloads\putty.exe] -ssh IP -l username -pw password
```

so that logs me in automatically on putty but what I need is for it to log me in and then run the command top straight away. Yes, I know it's lazy, but was wondering if it can be done?

Comment: Why don't you use another ssh client, maybe one has real command line support

Comment: Psioniax such as?

Comment: Do you just want to execute the command? Or do you want to keep continuing the SSH client after executing the command?

Comment: Martin Prikryl yes i want to open ssh and run the command "top" as soon as its logged in